# How to use Shared Preferences without extending AppCompatActivity to the class?

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

I need to use shared preferences in my class but when I use getSharedPreferences method it say
"Cannot resolve method 'getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'. Here's the code:

```
public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String data = "";



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e42776dd18e4016617690ce/3");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }



            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // THE ERROR
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

//            for(int i =0 ;i < JA.length(); i++) {
//                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
//                singleParsed =
//                        "id: " + JO.get("id") + "\n" +
//                      "img: " + JO.get("img") + "\n" +
//                        "w1: " + JO.get("w1") + "\n" +
//                        "w2: " + JO.get("w2") + "\n" +
//                        "w3: " + JO.get("w3") + "\n" +
//                        "w4: " + JO.get("w4") + "\n";
//
//                dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed + "\n";
//
//            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this,

```
 public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String data = "";
    Context context;

    FetchData (Context context){
     this.context = context;
    }

 }
```

and

```
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub library for sharePrefrence here is the link - [EasyPrefs Library](https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPrefs)

This library provides you functions of SharedPreference.